# Does registering with a performing rights organization conflict with licensing directly to a music supervisor?

Tags: professional-associations

Since Performance Rights Organizations collect royalties on plays on TV, cable etc., does this conflict with licensing your music directly with a music/sync supervisor?

For example, if I were to register with the digital PRO, SoundExchange, which claims to collect royalties on plays on cable and I were then to go to a music supervisor for a cable show who wanted to directly license the music, and if they paid me directly, what would happen when SoundExchange came knocking on their door to collect royalties? Would they be double charged? Or would they have to furnish proof that they'd obtained a sync license from me?

The reason I ask is somewhat of a followup question: If music supervisors risk being "double-charged", do they tend to avoid direct licensing with artists who are registered with a PRO? In other words, does registering with the PRO hurt my chances of being synced if I know music supervisors who would otherwise be interested in licensing my music?

(P.S. If I can make this more clear, please let me know how instead of blindly down-voting. This is a serious inquiry. Thank you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first half of your question, the easy route is to inform your PRO of the sync deal. Alternatively the sync supervisor can evidence it when asked.

It shouldn't put off any sync organisation, as the expectation is that most artists will be registered with at least one PRO.